# Remove border on activex ie control

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, activex, wxwidgets

For the application im building, i use an activex ie control. It works greate but i cant work out how to remove the border around it.

I have tried overriding the invoke call and setting DISPID_BORDERSTYLE to zero but it looks like it never gets hit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to implement IDocHostUIHandler on your host. then in GetHostInfo you can return the DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER or DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DOUTERBORDER flag.

Comment: thanks, with that tip it pointed me to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: It  would be very helpful if you would have posted some code. I wrote an answer with some C++ code for MFC here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923075/how-to-remove-3d-border-in-ie8-with-doctype-xhtml?answertab=active#tab-top